# android StateListAnimator in pre Lollipop

Tags: android, material-design

I've searched more and more, but I haven't found any answer. So tell me please how to use **AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator (..)** and **view.setStateListAnimator(..)** methods in pre Lollipop, is there any way to do instead of those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StateListAnimator is an Animator launched when a state has been changed. It's possible to implement that on older versions of Android. I'm working on backporting those in [Carbon](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon), but for now the library supports only elevation animation.

To implement a state animator extend [a View](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/widget/Button.java#L396), and override *drawableStateChanged*:

```
397     @Override 
398     protected void drawableStateChanged() { 
399         super.drawableStateChanged(); 
402         if (stateAnimators != null) 
403             for (StateAnimator animator : stateAnimators) 
404                 animator.stateChanged(getDrawableState()); 
405     }
```

Then implement [an animator](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/animation/ElevationStateAnimator.java#L23) with state animation you wish to have:

```
23     @Override 
24     protected void onPressedChanged() { 
25         if (pressed) { 
26             setTranslationZ(pressedElevation); 
27         } else { 
28             setTranslationZ(0); 
29         } 
30     } 
31 

32     private void setTranslationZ(float translationZ) { 
33         if (view.getTranslationZ() == translationZ || view.getElevation() == 0) 
34             return; 
35         ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(view.getTranslationZ(), translationZ); 
36         animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()); 
37         animator.setDuration(300); 
38         animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() { 
39             @Override 
40             public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) { 
41                 view.setTranslationZ((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue()); 
42             } 
43         }); 
44         animator.start(); 
45     }
```

And a simple [state change detector class](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon/blob/master/carbon/src/main/java/carbon/animation/StateAnimator.java#L10) (a superclass of each animator):

```
10     public void stateChanged(int[] states) { 
11         boolean newPressed = false, newEnabled = false, newChecked = false; 
12         for (int state : states) { 
13             if (state == android.R.attr.state_enabled) { 
14                 newEnabled = true; 
15             } else if (state == android.R.attr.state_pressed) { 
16                 newPressed = true; 
17             } else if (state == android.R.attr.state_checked) { 
18                 newChecked = true; 
19             } 
20         } 
21         if (pressed != newPressed) { 
22             pressed = newPressed; 
23             onPressedChanged(); 
24         } 
25         if (enabled != newEnabled) { 
26             enabled = newEnabled; 
27             onEnabledChanged(); 
28         } 
29         if (checked != newChecked) { 
30             checked = newChecked; 
31             onCheckedChanged(); 
32         } 
33     }
```

Having correct state animators for all views is pretty compicated and time consuming, but you can achieve that by adding animations in drawableStateChanged.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I've searched for. You save a lot of my time))